# Load error while trying to install cocoapods in MacBook Air running OSX 11.2.2 with Apple M1 chip

Tags: ios, cocoapods

On running pod install getting an error like this.

[!] Oh no, an error occurred while Analyzing dependencies

#### Error

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): missing compatible arch in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.14.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by below commands.

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod install
```